# How to select a column using SQL and then only use portion of the column to join with another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table A with column Ext - 7 characters. I want to join this with another table B which has a column Phone + ext - almost 17 characters in lenght. I want to use only the last 7 characters in the column in table B to join table A on Ext.

Comment: Which dbms, MySQL or SQL Server? The answer may depend on dbms...

Comment: you can join on arbitrary expressions. `join foo on bar=somefunc(baz)`. it won't be efficient, and almost always eliminates any chance of using an index, but it is perfectly allowable syntax.

Comment: I use SQL server. I do know to do joins, but I don't know to do this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT 1
FROM
   TableA a
   INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Ext = RIGHT(b.Phone, 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
From tableA a join tableB b
on substring(a.colPhoneExt, len(a.colPhoneExt)-7) = b.ext
```

Comment: thank you for your answer - I didn't try it because the answer above was simpler for me. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, never done it before(using joins like that is not good praxis). But should go something like:

select a.* from table1 a inner join table2 b
on  a.Ext = right(b.PhoneExt,7)

I presume the second table has 2 columns...Phone and Ext?

Comment: the second table has one column - wiht the phone and extension listed together in one column.